# How to implement change theme for an application?

Tags: android

Nowadays, I found that there are many apps that can change the theme (change button image/background image,etc). Users can go to Google Play and download the theme and the theme is automatically applied to the app.
But I don't understand how to implement because the background/button image should locate at the project file.
Please help to solve this questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be in app purchasing. The themes are already contained inside the application, you pay through google play to unlock the theme and allow it to be applied?

To set the theme at run time, you can call setTheme() during the onCreate() method of your activity, but it must be called before you setContentView().

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);
```

Comment: Your idea is great. But how to apply different theme inside the app?